# Understanding different behaviour of probes metal A and B

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

When Current-Voltage measurements are conducted on a semiconductor:
(i) With electrodes made of metal A.
(ii) With electrodes made of metal B.
the following traces are obtained (see figure attached). What could cause the same material exhibit different behaviour when the probe metals are changed? What would be the shape of the curve if one contact is made of metal-A and the other contact is made of metal-B?

[image]

Comment: i)the electrodes cannot be made of a metal.

Comment: See Schottky barrier...

Answer (score 0):

There is something called the *schottky effect* where it is possible for a voltage bias to arise across a pressure junction between a semiconductor and a metal. This can make the resulting junction behave like a diode over a certain range of applied voltages.